# How to make async call to api (http). in c#. inside a Task

Tags: async-await, task, botframework

I am developeing a chatbot using microsoftbotframmwok where I have some requirement to make a call from my task to an api(httpclient). but it is not working. when i test the api from an stand alone console application in side main method it works. but in my application it doesn't work.

I tried to call an api from an simple method without task but when it makes a cal its basically halts or stucked somewhere, i converted my function into task and while making an api call i used await keyword to call it asynchronously but it is returning error, while reading it not the result.

here is the my code which make an api call

```
private async Task<String> getProblem(IDialogContext context)
{
            var response = "Thannks for contacting..";

       //here some code logix..


            SnowApiClient client = new SnowApiClient(Url, UserId, ApiPassword);
            IncidentRequestPayload payload = new IncidentRequestPayload();
            payload.caller_id = "tet111";
            payload.assignment_group = "it";
            payload.category = "complaint";
            payload.u_feedback_type = "Praise";
            payload.service_offering = "Application Management";
            payload.priority = 2;
            payload.short_description = "computer battery is dead";
            payload.comments = String.Empty;

           ApiResponse objResponse = await client.CreateIncident(payload);
       //objResponse.payload.number;
           return response;
}

//code for CreateIncident...in Api project librarary

     public async Task<ApiResponse> CreateIncident(IncidentRequestPayload payload)
            {
                var incidentRequest = new ApiRequest { method = CreateIncidentMethod, payload = payload };
                var createResult = await ExecuteRequest(incidentRequest);
                return await ReadIncident(createResult.payload.incNumber);
            }

public async Task<ApiResponse> ReadIncident(string number)
        {
            var incidentRequest = new ApiRequest { method = ReadIncidentMethod, payload = new RequestPayload { number = number } };
            return await ExecuteRequest(incidentRequest);
        }

private async Task<ApiResponse> ExecuteRequest(ApiRequest requestObject)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("/SRintegratedAPI.rest", requestObject);

            ApiResponse responseObject = null;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseObject = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResponse>();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new System.Net.WebException(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            if (responseObject.result != "ok")
            {
                throw new System.Net.WebException(responseObject.message);
            }

            return responseObject;
        }
```

I don't understand how and where do i used async/await here in basicalaly in my getProblem function.
please help

Comment: Are you calling `Wait` or `Result` further up your call stack?

Comment: I tried with ApiResponse objResponse = await client.CreateIncident(payload).Wait() and Result also but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm not telling you to do that. I'm asking if anywhere up your call stack you are already doing that.

Comment: No, I am not doing that. I cross checked that.

Comment: Then you'll need to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try - await client.MyMethod(blah...).ConfigureAwait(false);